# R - getting back single element from strsplit

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a character vector separated by "_".  I want to loop through each string split it and then use the individual values to grab specific rows/cols of a csv file to do some calculations.  How can I get the individual elements?

```
tst <- c("Test1_Test2","Test3_Test4")

splt <- strsplit(tst,"_")
splt

[[1]]
[1] "Test1" "Test2"

[[2]]
[1] "Test3" "Test4"
```

How can I get the single value into a variable? i.e.

```
str1 <- "Test1"
str2 <- "Test2"
str3 <- "Test3"
str4 <- "Test4"
```

Edit:  I always figure it out right after I post the question lol.

```
splt[[1]][1]
[1] "Test1"
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically `strsplit` will be applied to every single element of `tst` object. And it will be something likes this:

```
> strsplit(tst, "_")
[[1]]
[1] "Test1" "Test2"

[[2]]
[1] "Test3" "Test4"
```

Then you can break that down into a single vector by using `unlist`

```
> unlist(strsplit(tst, "_"))
[1] "Test1" "Test2" "Test3" "Test4"
```

Then you can loop through every word depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
for (elem in unlist(strsplit(tst, "_"))){
  print(elem)
}

> [1] "Test1"
> [1] "Test2"
> [1] "Test3"
> [1] "Test4"
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is probably the better way to do it then I did.